# Passing PHP Variables To Ajax Functions Converting Variables JS To PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having real problems understanding the logic of passing information from PHP to JS and back. I have been up all night working on this and would really appreciate if someone can show me how to pass two variables to an ajax function.

$assetPath and $count in to the lines commented below. I have tried including them by adding php but in the DOM it shows up as an empty string and I cannot get the desired outcome.

```
var assetPath ='<?php echo $assetPath; ?>';
var num ='<?php echo $count; ?>';

(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.pager-top,.pager-bottom').bootpag({
    total: assetPath,
    page: 1,
    maxVisible: 5,
    leaps: true,
    firstLastUse: true,
    first: '←',
    last: '→',
    wrapClass: 'pagination',
    activeClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    nextClass: 'next',
    prevClass: 'prev',
    lastClass: 'last',
    firstClass: 'first'
}).on("page", function(event, num){
    $.ajax({
            url: "assetPath?pageNumber="+num,
            }).done(function(data) {
            $("#productResults").html( data );
             });
});
})( jQuery );
});
```

Comment: So `$assetPath` really have a value inside?

Comment: assetPath has a url path in it. Seriously this has made me feel stupid. I have not slept yet cause I really want to understand this. Please explain it to me man. the basic concepts of passing data back and forth and ajax. I have been through tons of tutorials and once I think I have it I cant get anything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if the Php variable really hold the value and data do exist inside it, then by using this kind of code `var assetPath ='<?php echo $assetPath; ?>';` would fine. Before testing into js environment, try echo into page the variables send from server side to see the data do exist or not. And for ajax stuff, to be sure, please used `data` properties provided for sending data into server side end point, see following example :

```
var assetPath ='<?php echo $assetPath; ?>';
var num ='<?php echo $count; ?>';

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url: assetPath,//<-- is it this came from variable assetPath??
    data : {
     pageNumber : num,
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#productResults").html( data );
});
```

And in server side, assume the `assetpath` holding value `process.php` :

```
 $_POST['pageNumber']; //<-- retrieve data sent from ajax
```

And if you `echo $_POST['pageNumber'];` after above code, then this value will available inside success/done block of ajax :

```
.done(function(data) {
  // data is a data sent from server side
  $("#productResults").html( data );
});
```

Comment: If course, this will only work if this javascript code is in the .php page itself, not in a separate .js file.

Comment: @HaukurHaf : of course mate, otherwise the variable `assetPath` will printed out `<?php echo $assetPath; ?>` as a string rather than empty string in a DOM like OP said

Comment: Just thought it was worth mentioning for others as well, since nothing in his script indicates that it's *not* in a separate .js file (it might as well have been).

Comment: Actually all my data is in a seperate php file which gets all the data from a table in the database. in this page I an display the data in a table and trying to paginate it. Currently the ajax function you can see gets the data but it is not displaying it properly I think its because I am not handling each one of the parameters of the ajax function properly.

Comment: You do need to handle them properly, and please do sending correctly data from server side

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your vars into your `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){

var assetPath ='<?php echo $assetPath; ?>';
var num ='<?php echo $count; ?>';

$('.pager-top,.pager-bottom').bootpag({
    total: assetPath,
    page: 1,
    maxVisible: 5,
    leaps: true,
    firstLastUse: true,
    first: '←',
    last: '→',
    wrapClass: 'pagination',
    activeClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    nextClass: 'next',
    prevClass: 'prev',
    lastClass: 'last',
    firstClass: 'first'
}).on("page", function(event, num){
    $.ajax({
            url: "assetPath?pageNumber="+num,
            }).done(function(data) {
            $("#productResults").html( data );
             });
});
})( jQuery );
});
```

Hope this will work :)

Comment: If course, this will only work if this javascript code is in the .php page itself, not in a separate .js file.